# retrieve data of collection type from database using getters and setters

Tags: java, hibernate

i am having three classes one is USER, second Vehicle and third is notfound_test.
In USER class i declared vehicle as Collection as follow.
    **Collection vehicle=new ArrayList();**
And also having getters and setters of it.
So, my question is how i can retrieve data from database i am using hibernate?
I tried following code.
**i am unable from getting data in JOPTIONPANE OF VEHICLE IN THIRD CLASS.i wanted the associated data**

```
package org.notfound.annotation;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.OneToMany;

@Entity
public class User {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private int id;
private String name;
@OneToMany
Collection<Vehicle> vehicle=new ArrayList<Vehicle>();


public Collection<Vehicle> getVehicle() {
    return vehicle;
}
public void setVehicle(Collection<Vehicle> vehicle) {
    this.vehicle = vehicle;
}
public int getId() {
    return id;
}
public void setId(int id) {
    this.id = id;
}
public String getName() {
    return name;
}
public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}


}

package org.notfound.annotation;

import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.ManyToOne;

@Entity
public class Vehicle {

@Id @GeneratedValue
private int vehicle_id;
private String vehicle_name;
@ManyToOne
private User user=new User();



public User getUser() {
    return user;
}
public void setUser(User user) {
    this.user = user;
}
public int getVehicle_id() {
    return vehicle_id;
}
public void setVehicle_id(int vehicle_id) {
    this.vehicle_id = vehicle_id;
}
public String getVehicle_name() {
    return vehicle_name;
}
public void setVehicle_name(String vehicle_name) {
    this.vehicle_name = vehicle_name;
}


}

 package org.notfound.annotation;

 import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

 import org.hibernate.Session;
 import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
 import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;

 public class Notfound_test {


public static void main(String[] args) {

    User user=new User();
    Vehicle vehicle=new Vehicle();
    Vehicle vehicle2=new Vehicle();

    user.setName("NIRAV J. KAMANI");
    vehicle.setVehicle_name("CHEVROLET CRUIZE");
    vehicle2.setVehicle_name("MARUTI ERTIGA");
    vehicle.setUser(user);
    vehicle2.setUser(user);
    user.getVehicle().add(vehicle);
    user.getVehicle().add(vehicle2);

    SessionFactory sessionfactory=new Configuration().configure().buildSessionFactory();
    Session session=sessionfactory.openSession();
    /*session.beginTransaction();
    session.save(user);
    session.save(vehicle);
    session.save(vehicle2);
    session.getTransaction().commit();
    session.close();*/

    session.beginTransaction();
    user=(User) session.get(User.class, 1);
    vehicle=(Vehicle) session.get(Vehicle.class, 1);
    vehicle2=(Vehicle) session.get(Vehicle.class, 2);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, user.getId()+" "+user.getName()+" "+user.getVehicle().toString(), "INFORMATION", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    session.close();

}

}
```

Comment: So, what's the problem. What does this code do? What is displayed in the JOptionPane?

Comment: i am getting following.1 NIRAV J. KAMANI [org.notfound.annotation.Vehicle@37ed25, org.notfound.annotation.Vehicle@aec63]

Comment: See the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As always, you forgot the mappedBy annotation on the OneToMany. It's a bidirectional OneToMany association, and the one side must thus be the inverse side of the many side, as explained [in the documentation](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#collections-bidirectional):

```
@OneToMany(mappedBy = "user")
private Collection<Vehicle> vehicles = new ArrayList<Vehicle>();
```

I also renamed the fields to `vehicles`, since it's a collection, and thus contains several ones.

EDIT:

Your comment shows that the 2 vehicles **are** printed:

```
[org.notfound.annotation.Vehicle@37ed25, org.notfound.annotation.Vehicle@aec63]
 ^-- first vehicle                       ^-- second vehicle
^-- brackets, indicating that it's a collection ------------------------------^
```

If you want them to be printed is a different way than the dafult way, you need to override the `toString()` method in vehicle, as for any Java object.

Comment: unable to undertand...,it must print chevrolet cruize and maruti ertiga.. i already written tostring()

Comment: There is no toString() method in the Vehicle code you posted. Why don't you show us this method?

Comment: user.getVehicle().toString() in joptionpane

Comment: You're **calling** toString() on a **collection** of vehicles (see why the final *s* is useful? You confused yourself). The collection transforms itself into a String by outputting a bracket, then the `toString()` of every Vehicle it contains, separated by commas, then a closing bracket. Since Vehicle doesn't have any toString() method, the default one, from Object, is used. This is extremely basic OO stuff that you should understand before using Hibernate.

Comment: can you tell me what can i do?

Comment: Override `toString()` in Vehicle. Or implement a method that iterates through the collection of vehicles and generates the string you want based on the state of the vehicles.